# Share data with singleton implementation

Tags: objective-c

I have to share many static NSStrings between all my classes .
I want to use a singleton .

I have tried this singleton  :

```
static GlobalData *sharedSingleton = NULL;

    + (GlobalData *)sharedGlobals
    {
        @synchronized(self)
        {
            if (sharedSingleton == NULL)
                sharedSingleton = [[self alloc] init];
        }

       //should i put a nsstring here ?            

        return(sharedSingleton);
    }
```

My question is, where do i set my static `NSStrings` and how ?

Comment: How is `GlobalData` related to static `NSString`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your static strings the same way as an ordinary class, meaning you declare them in the @interface, and you can initialize them in your singleton initializer. A singleton is used exactly the same as any object, except that you only have one instance of it (which is monitored by the static variable `sharedSingleton`).

Also, if you're using the same strings from many objects, and they remain constant during the app's lifecycle, you might as well consider just declaring your strings as constants with `#define`.

EDIT
The declarations should be something like

```
@interface GlobalData
@property NSString *myString;
...
@end
```

And from any part of your code.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[GlobalData sharedGlobals] myString];
```

Comment: Thanks but if i set a string as usual in the interface, i don't see hem from the outside using [globalData sharedGlobals].string

Comment: @Curnelious Please show more code, it is unclear what you mean by 'set a string as usual in the interface'.